# JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize json string separated by comma to list<string>

Tags: c#, .net, json

I've following type

```
class ToDoElement{


 public int id;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public List<string> tags;
}
```

And also i have some json string:

```
string msg = "{"title":"someTitle", "description":"someDescription", "tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3"}
```

When i'm trying to parse it by JavaScriptSerializer:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ();
ToDoElement o = js.Deserialize<ToDoElement> (msg);
```

I'm getting exception

> "Cannot convert string to List".

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
"tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3"
```

Isn't a proper JSON array, it should look like this:

```
"tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

If you can't change your JSON, you'll need to parse it into an intermediate object. I'm going to be using Json.NET for this example:

```
dynamic intermediateObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(msg); 
ToDoElement = new ToDoElement 
{
    Title = intermediateObj.title,
    Description = intermediateObj.description,
    Tags = intermediateObj.tags.Split(',').Select(str => str.Trim())
                                          .ToList();
}
```

Note I've added the `string.Trim` call as well. You can remove it if not needed.

Answer (score 2):

`tags` is just a string with comma separated words inside:

```
 "tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3"
```

You would need to deserialize into the following field:

```
 public string tags;
```

Later, you could split then with [`string.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`string.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you still want a list of tags to appear in your classes, you could deserialize the `"tags"` property as a proxy property, like so:

```
class ToDoElement
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public string tags
    {
        get
        {
            if (TagList == null)
                return null;
            return string.Join(", ", TagList.ToArray());
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                TagList = null;
                return;
            }
            TagList = value.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public List<string> TagList { get; set; }
}
```